# Пример мира с гравитацией и землей

Tags: box2d, c++

Здравствуйте, кто знает, где есть хороший справочник по Box2D? Я не совсем понял, как сказать созданному миру, что некое тело принадлежит ему...
Вот пока на что меня хватило:

```
b2AABB worldAABB; //что это за мир???

b2World *world;// И это что за мир??? в чем отличие от верхнего????

b2Vec2 position;
main
{

    worldAABB.lowerBound.Set(0.0f, 0.0f);
        worldAABB.upperBound.Set(1441.0f, 900.0f);

        b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -5.0f);
        bool doSleep = true;// grav vector

        b2World world(worldAABB, gravity, doSleep);

        b2BodyDef groundBodyDef, *groundBody;
        groundBodyDef.position.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);

        b2Body* ground = world.CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);

        b2PolygonDef groundShapeDef;
    groundShapeDef.SetAsBox(50.0f, 10.0f);

    //groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox, 0.0f); похоже вывод на экран

    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.position.Set(0.0f, 4.0f);
    b2Body* body = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    b2PolygonDef shapeDef;
    shapeDef.SetAsBox(1.0f, 1.0f);
    shapeDef.density = 1.0f;
    shapeDef.friction = 0.3f;
    body->CreateShape(&shapeDef);
    body->SetMassFromShapes();

    float32 timeStep = 1.0f / 60.0f;
    int32 iterations = 10;

    //for (int32 i = 0; i < 8000; ++i)
    //{
         world.Step(timeStep, iterations);
         position = body->GetPosition();
         float32 angle = body->GetAngle();
         Show(position);
         printf("%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f\n", position.x, position.y, angle);
    //}

    b2PolygonDef triangleDef;
    triangleDef.vertexCount = 3;
    triangleDef.vertices[0].Set(-1.0f, 0.0f);
    triangleDef.vertices[1].Set(1.0f, 0.0f);
    triangleDef.vertices[2].Set(0.0f, 2.0f);

        //GameManager().Run();
    }
```

Не могли бы показать для шаблона и точной уверенности в верности написания, как создается мир с гравитацией и землей, и какой-нибудь квадрат, или круг в этом мире??? Я насоздавал пока сам не пойму что. Да и в примерах у них нагорожено. Сделали бы несколько более простых примеров что ли. И вроде гравитация у меня не работает.
В общем, нужен мир 320 на 480 пикселей с гравитацией, и объект в мире.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну конечно есть, есть даже туториалы как создать свою маленькую игру, все есть  [здесь.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls)

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо. Уже читаю!)

Comment: Да, читайте лучше документацию оригинальную то есть на оригинальном языке без первода, а то перевод иногда бывает кривой.